# Using FieldPath.documentId() (equals) throws 'Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties' if inequality filter is present in the query

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Query

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("my_collection")
                    .whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), docId)
                    .whereEqualTo("int_field", intValue)
                    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("another_int_field", anotherIntValue);
```

throws

```
"INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot have inequality filters on multiple properties: another_int_field"
```

If I remove filtering by `documentId`, it works:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("my_collection")
                    .whereEqualTo("int_field", intValue)
                    .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("another_int_field", anotherIntValue);
```

If I remove filtering by `another_int_field`, it also works:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("my_collection")
                    .whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), docId)
                    .whereEqualTo("int_field", intValue);
```

The way I see it, `whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), docId)`
gets treated as if it were inequality filter, but gets ignored at error reporting.

Why? How? What am I missing?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to chain any other condition at all after `whereEqualTo(FieldPath.documentId(), docId)`, since that condition is always guaranteed to find exactly 0 or 1 documents (since every document id in a collection must be unique), and no more.  Adding more conditions will only ever change the number of documents from 1 to 0, and it will still cost you 1 document read.  Error message aside, what are you really trying to accomplish with this query?

Comment: Well, to not return document I have no use for, nothing more.
I could have ignored this issue, returned document and filter it out on device.
But it bugs me. I need to know. :)

Comment: You could look at the source code.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/tree/master/firebase-firestore

Comment: I could. And I did.
But didn't find it in a reasonable amount of time, so here I am. If anyone knows and is willing to share the answer - great! If not, oh well, this mystery will just have to wait a little longer.

Comment: Facing something similar. Did you ever find and answer?